# Misma consulta con diferente respuesta

Tags: php, mysqli

Buen día:
Para trabajar tome lo esencial y funcionó.

```
$sql021x = "SELECT * FROM $t00 WHERE 00_idpac= '3' ";

//$id el 3 reemplaza al $id sólo para no andar pasando por el buscador.
```

Para después incluir los join (que todavía no están) reemplacé el `*` por los nombres de tabla y campo:

```
$sql021x = "SELECT $t00.00_apellido, 
                   $t00.00_nombres,
                   $t00.00_fenacim,
                   $t00.00_nacional, 
                   $t00.00_dni, 
                   $t00.00_domicili,
                   $t00.00_localida,
                   $t00.00_cp,
                   $t00.00_partido,
                   $t00.00_contacto,
                   $t00.00_telcelu,
                   $t00.00_telfijo,
                   $t00.00_email,
                   $t00.00_relfami,
                   $t00.00_oscobert,
                   $t00.00_nucobert,
                   $t00.00_tienecud,
                   $t00.00_fevenccud,
                   $t00.00_diagnost,
                   $t00.00_motivocons,
                   $t00.00_proforien,
                   $t00.00_feorien,
                   $t00.00_hoorien,
                   $t00.00_observac,
                   $t00.00_iduser,
                   $t00.00_carga,
                   $t00.00_idpac 
            FROM $t00  
            WHERE 00_idpac= '3' ";
```

Y la respuesta es:

> ERROR: No es posible ejecutar la consulta SELECT 00_dato_pac.00_apellido, 00_dato_pac.00_nombres, 00_dato_pac.00_fenacim, 00_dato_pac.00_nacional, 00_dato_pac.00_dni, 00_dato_pac.00_domicili, 00_dato_pac.00_localida, 00_dato_pac.00_cp, 00_dato_pac.00_partido, 00_dato_pac.00_contacto, 00_dato_pac.00_telcelu, 00_dato_pac.00_telfijo, 00_dato_pac.00_email, 00_dato_pac.00_relfami, 00_dato_pac.00_oscobert, 00_dato_pac.00_nucobert, 00_dato_pac.00_tienecud, 00_dato_pac.00_fevenccud, 00_dato_pac.00_diagnost, 00_dato_pac.00_motivocons, 00_dato_pac.00_proforien, 00_dato_pac.00_feorien, 00_dato_pac.00_hoorien, 00_dato_pac.00_observac, 00_dato_pac.00_iduser, 00_dato_pac.00_carga, 00_dato_pac.00_idpac FROM 00_dato_pac WHERE 00_idpac= '3'.

Me siento confundida

Alguien por acá que entienda o sepa que macana me mandé?

Comment: El error no menciona si es por algún error de sintaxis, o nombre de tabla o columna desconocido?

Comment: hola podrias explicarte que es lo que quieres obtener?? y tal vez mostrar la estructura de las tablas con las que quieres trabajar , saludos

Comment: No copie el error tal cual aparece

Comment: Es una tabla simple donde como se puede ver trabajo con nombres, apellidos y demás datos personales de un paciente.
@fer, No hay nada raro excepto que cuando pongo todos los campos en vez de * me contesta que no puede hacer la consulta

Comment: Haz la misma consulta sin la variable $t00. Conservala solo en el from

Comment: pruebo, mismo error sin una coma de diferencia @Hoose

Comment: @SilviaGaviotaGarcia coloca alias a las columnas `Ejemplo: $t00.00_apellido AS Apellido`, tal vez los caracteres especiales `Ejemplo: $` pueda ocasionar problemas. También revisa si efectivamente esas columnas existen en la tabla. También usa `mysqli_error()` para revisar el error del mensaje después de ejecutar la consulta. **[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434814/cant-execute-a-sql-query-mysql-php#comment34117413_22434814)**.

Comment: Intento, gracias. Las columnas existen todas. El $t00 es una variable que llama a la tabla en este caso a la 00_dato_pac no me dio problemas hasta ahora, pero lo de los alias es una idea. me fijo y te cuento

Comment: Puede ser que los saltos de línea no estén permitidos. Prueba con dos campos sin saltos de linea EJ:  
`sql021x = "SELECT $t00.00_apellido, $t00.00_nombres FROM $t00 WHERE 00_idpac = '3'"`

Comment: Uní las dos respuestas le puse alias a 4 campos y sí funciona. Gracias @MauricioAriasOlave

Comment: @SilviaGaviotaGarcia, que bueno que haya funcionado. Colocaré la respuesta para que así la puedas aceptar; además, a otros usuarios les será de utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente:

> - Coloca alias a las columnas. Ejemplo: `$t00.00_apellido AS Apellido`. Tal vez los caracteres especiales *Ejemplo: `$`* pueda
>     ocasionar problemas.
> - También revisa si efectivamente esas columnas existen en la tabla.
> - También usa `mysqli_error()` para revisar el error del mensaje después de ejecutar la consulta<sup>1</sup>.

Aporte de [Asero82 en su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108847/misma-consulta-con-diferente-respuesta?noredirect=1#comment201887_108847):

Puede ser que los saltos de línea no estén permitidos. Prueba con dos campos sin saltos de linea.

Ejemplo: `sql021x = "SELECT $t00.00_apellido, $t00.00_nombres FROM $t00 WHERE 00_idpac = '3'"`

---

<sup>1</sup> [Fuente: Comentario en la pregunta Can't execute a sql query (mysql, php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434814/cant-execute-a-sql-query-mysql-php#comment34117413_22434814)